# deciphering a export default connect statement in a react component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to figure out an internal web project that uses React, Redux, and Redux-Saga.

There is one React component that seems vastly more complicated than the rest of the project, and I just can't figure out what the heck is going on.

I'm failing miserably trying to decipher what is going on in the *export default connect statement* at the bottom of the code block.

Specifically, I see that these two objects/things are getting passed as props to the **VehicleFuelType** component:

- onReaction
- onConfigurePropulsion
- fuelType

But I fail to see what is happening to those objects in the *export default connect statement*.

I've read through a bunch of redux documentation, but it's still a mystery to me.

If anyone knows whats actually happening in this code block, could you please share the knowledge?

Thanks!

```
class vehicleDisplay extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onConfigurePropulsion();
}

render() {

    return (
       <div>
           {fuelType.valueSeq().map(f =>
             <div>    
               <VehiclefuelType
                   key={f.id}
                   fuelType={f}
                   reaction={reactions.find(r => r.fuelTypeId === f.id)}
                   onReaction={!fatalReaction ? () => onReaction(f.id) : () => null}
               />
            </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default connect(
    (state, { propulsionId, currentVehicleId }) => ({
        propulsion: state.propulsions.get(propulsionId),
        fuelTypes: state.fuelTypes.filter(f => f.propulsionId === propulsionId),
        reactions: state.reactions.filter(r => r.propulsionId === propulsionId),
    }),
    (dispatch, { propulsionId }) => ({
        onConfigurePropulsion: () => dispatch(Actions.configurePropulsion(propulsionId)),
        onReaction: (fuelTypeId) => dispatch(Actions.saveReaction(propulsionId, alternativeId))
    })
)(vehicleDisplay)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connect` takes in two arguments, `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. These are usually separated off into their own variables, but this person did them inline. The first argument here is retrieving values from the state and putting them into your component's `props`. The second is setting up dispatches for redux actions that can then also be accessed via `props`. More info can be found [here](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react).

Comment: oh ok, so to make it more readable, I could assign those two arguments like: mapStateToProps = (stuff) and mapDispatchToProps = (stuff) then just have "export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), correct? thanks

Comment: Yep! Just copy over those functions into their own variables and you should be solid.